# Travis for C++ always ignore script for customize testing

Tags: c++, travis-ci

I've been experimenting this and spend more than 25 commit with only small change in `.travis.yml` but travis always do either:

1. **./configure**: if I put the `language: cpp` in the first line. travis will ignore everything written in .travis.yml and will go straight `./configure && make && make test`

   ```
   language: cpp

   addons:
     apt:
       sources:
       - ubuntu-sdk-team

   addons:
     apt:
       packages:
       - ubuntu-sdk

   before_script: ls

   script: qmake demo/QtGoodiesDemo/QtGoodiesDemo.pro && make

   sudo: false
   ```
2. **rake**: if I reorder the placement of `language: cpp` or remove it. this point, travis succeeded install the dependency (apt addons executed)

   ```
   addons:
     apt:
       sources:
       - ubuntu-sdk-team

   addons:
     apt:
       packages:
       - ubuntu-sdk

   before_script: ls

   script: qmake demo/QtGoodiesDemo/QtGoodiesDemo.pro && make

   language: cpp
   sudo: false
   ```

I have read the documentation and using what it told just lead me to the point (1) problem.

I've searched but nobody got this problem, I wonder how people do this.

([This is the link](https://travis-ci.org/imakin/QtGoodies))

## Attempt 1

using nested apt source still gets me to problem(1) and ignore the custom script (https://travis-ci.org/imakin/QtGoodies/builds/85143452). Note that in problem 2 when rake is called, it succeeded in installing ubuntu-sdk for the Qt dependencies

```
language: cpp
sudo: false

addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-sdk-team
    packages:
      - ubuntu-sdk

before_script: ls

script: qmake demo/QtGoodiesDemo/QtGoodiesDemo.pro && make
```

## Attempt 2

So then I try to play it and added configure file. Having it all rwxrwxrwx permission too. and pushed it. But travis still execute to problem (1) again. No Qt Installing, even failed to run the configure telling it has no permission to execute it. I can't do anything to chmod it in testing process though as before_script is ignored too. This one occurred in https://travis-ci.org/imakin/QtGoodies/builds/85146543

Comment: OK. I don't know Travis very well, but can you expand on the problem description in the title, in the body of the post? I am not sure there is enough detail as to the problem you're actually experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `.travis.yml` file is invalid and prevents it to be parsed properly, hence you default to the Ruby language.

Can you try merging both `addons.apt` sections like so:

```
addons:
  apt:
    sources:
      - ubuntu-sdk-team
    packages:
      - ubuntu-sdk
```

Hope this helps!

**Update**: it turns out the .travis.yml file started with a hidden character that prevented Travis CI from parsing it properly.

Comment: Hello! I've tried as your suggest but it seems not the problem. Using the unmerged addons apt still succeed in installing that (case 2 when rake is called). i've updated the question. travis still ignore the script

Comment: It seems you have a hidden character in your .travis.yml file which is preventing Travis CI from parsing it properly. I opened a pull request: https://github.com/imakin/QtGoodies/pull/1.